# Elasticsearch, dealing with null values in date field

Tags: regex

I have the following string.

```
 MUST  (key1=value1)(key2>value2)NOT (key3=value3) SHOULD  (key4=value4)
```

And I need to split it into three strings.

```
MUST(key1=value1)(key2>value2)
NOT(key3=value3)
SHOULD(key4=value4)
```

Some statements, for example, NOT or SHOULD could be absent. So, I must match the end of the line also.

For now, I came up with a regex like this `/(MUST)?.*(?=NOT)/`

But it doesn't work if SHOULD is before NOT or there is only MUST. How can I add OR operator here, something like `(?=NOT|SHOULD|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about matching each part that starts with one of the keywords until the next keyword (or end of string):

```
\b(?:MUST|NOT|SHOULD)\b(?:(?!\b(?:MUST|NOT|SHOULD)\b).)*
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xG2dM1/1).

**Explanation:**

```
\b(?:MUST|NOT|SHOULD)\b       # Match one of the keywords
(?:                           # Start of non-capturing group:
 (?!\b(?:MUST|NOT|SHOULD)\b)  # Unless we're at the start of another keyword:
 .                            # Match any character
)*                            # Repeat as often as possible
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. I voted your answer. The vote will be visible when I have enough reputation.